# How to hide warnings from xgboost library in jupyter?

Tags: xgboost

Not working:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

The warning I get:

```
[14:24:45] WARNING: C:/Jenkins/workspace/xgboost-win64_release_0.90/src/objective/regression_obj.cu:152: reg:linear is now deprecated in favor of reg:squarederror.
```

It clutters my output in cell.

Comment: found it, XGBRegressor(objective ='reg:squarederror')

Comment: please put your comment as an answer to help others

Answer (score 30):

Change the verbosity parameter `verbosity = 0` in the model definition. The values it can take are: 0 - "silent", 1 - "warning", 2 - "info", 3 - "debug"

```
xgboost = xgb.XGBRegressor(objective ='reg:linear', verbosity = 0, random_state=42)
```

[XGBoost Documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html)

Comment: This is actually the only answer that works (in 2020). silent=True does not work, neither does warnings.filterwarnings('ignore') if you are about to try that. Not sure if this has to do with XGBRegressor not actually classifying its warning messages correctly? Nonetheless verbosity = 0 is what kills of the 100's of endless warnings that occur during a gridsearch for example.

Comment: VSCode, Jupyter, Python 3.8, Linux Mint - works, but doesn't quiet UserWarnings.

Answer (score 5):

Just add `silent = True` in the model's definition:

```
xgboost = xgb.XGBRegressor(random_state=42,silent=True)
```

Comment: This added even more warnings!

Comment: Use both as @darkstar-dream verbose=0 and silent=True

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and adding both `verbose=0` and `silent=True` helped me

```py
xgboost = xgb.XGBRegressor(objective ='reg:linear', verbosity = 0, silent=True, random_state=42)
```

Comment: But, does it show other useful information? Let's say I don't want warnings, but want other kinds of outputs. Does it work for that?